# How can I show it?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f$ be an absolute continuous function in $(0, 1)$ and satisfies 
$$
|f(x+h)+f(x-h)-2f(x)|\leq \text{const}\frac{|h|}{(\log\frac{1}{|h|})^{\gamma}} ,
$$ 
where $\gamma \in (0, 1)$ and $|h|$- is sufficiently small. 
Q: Is following 
$$
\int_{|h|}^{1-|h|}|f'(x+|h|)-f'(x)|dx\leq \text{const}\frac{1}{(\log\frac{1}{|h|})^{\gamma}}  
$$
  inequality true? If it is how can I show?

Comment: Can you use Taylor expansions about $0$ (since you've said $|h|<1$)?

Comment: Yes. It is a good idea if $f\in C^{1}$

Comment: Upto a first order, then, you can Taylor expand to get $f(x+h)=f(x)+\frac{df}{dx}h+\mathcal{O}(h^2)$. Thus, $|f(x+h)+f(x-h)-2f(x)|=|f(x)+\frac{df}{dx}h+f(x)-\frac{df}{dx}h-2f(x)|=0$. Also, $f^{'}(x+h)-f^{'}(x)=f^{'}(x)+\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}h-f^{'}(x)=\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}h$.

Comment: How do you know existence of $\frac{df}{dx}$ and $\frac{d^{2}f}{dx^{2}}$

Comment: Since $f\in C^1$, $\frac{df}{dx}$ exists. Without the existence of the second derivative of $f$, $f^{'}(x+h)−f^{'}(x)$ vanishes.

Comment: Yes, you are right. If $f\in C^{1}$ then it is clear. But in my case $f$ is an absolutely continuous and satisfies above inequality  generally from these assumptions does not implies $f\in C^{1}$

Comment: If $f\in C^\infty$, then $f^{'}(x+h)−f^{'}(x)=\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}h$. Integrate this.

Comment: @UwF Since $f$ absolutely continuous, $f'$ exist almost everywhere and $f'\in L^{1}$.

Comment: @ Sanath. I don't understand your the last comment.

Comment: Good note. The meaning of the inequalities are following: since $(0, 1)$ is open, for every $x\in (0, 1)$ there exist a $h,$  $|h|<1$ (maybe it is sufficient small) s.t. $x,$ $x+h$ and $x-h$ belong $(0,1).$